# Gesture (Orientation) events not being called in titanium alloy

Tags: ios, iphone, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I am developing an app on titanium for the first time and working with the orientation changes. I am using Titanium Alloy framework to build my app.

The way I am working with views is:

1. I have a view where I have a navigation window and a window used.
2. All the child views are loaded in the navigation window.
3. When I navigate through the views the back navigation is automatically handled.

I run this in simulator and when I change the orientation, the orientation event doesn't get called. I am not sure even if its being added or not. Am I missing something here? I have already tried the `Titanium.Gesture.isPortrait()` and `Titanium.Gesture.isLandscape()` but to no avail.

Below is the code, the parent window looks like this:

```
<Alloy>
    <NavigationWindow id="challengeNav">
        <Window title="Mobile Mentor" onOpen="loadChallenges" class="container" barColor="#003363"  fullscreen="true">

            <!-- Controls -->

        </Window>
    </NavigationWindow> 
</Alloy>
```

The Child View where I am using the Orientation change looks like following:

```
<Window class="container" title="Challenge Video" barColor="#003363" onOpen="addGestureChangeEvent"  fullscreen="true">
    <RightNavButton>
        <Button title="Next" onClick="recordResponse" />
    </RightNavButton>
    <View id= "videoContainer">
          <VideoPlayer id="challengeVideoPlayer" ns="Ti.Media" autoplay="false" volume="1" scalingMode="Titanium.Media.SCALING_ASPECT_FILL" />
    </View>

</Window>
```

The JS controller for the the Child View is:

```
var args = arguments[0] || {};
var currUser = Alloy.Globals.CurrentUser;
var challengeNav = Alloy.Globals.ChallengeNavParent;
var orientation = Titanium.Gesture.orientation;

var challengeData = args;

$.challengeVideoPlayer.url = challengeData.Challenge.VideoUrl;
$.txtOptionalTip.value = challengeData.Challenge.OptionalTip != undefined ? challengeData.Challenge.OptionalTip : "Optional Tip not available";

function addGestureChangeEvent(e) {

}

Titanium.Gesture.addEventListener("onOrientationChanged", function(evt) {
    alert("Gesture Change");
    orientation = Titanium.Gesture.orientation;
    if (orientation === 3 || orientation === 4) {
        alert("Gesture Change Landscape");
        $.challengeVideoPlayer.fullscreen = true;

    } else {
        alert("Gesture Change Portrait");
        $.challengeVideoPlayer.fullscreen = false;
    }
});

function recordResponse(e) {
    $.challengeVideoPlayer.stop();

    //$.challengeVideoPlayer.release(); //This code releases the internal video resource of the video player.
    var challengeResponseController = Alloy.createController("challengeResponse", challengeData).getView();
    challengeNav.openWindow(challengeResponseController);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding listener for wrong event name. There is no event name `onOrientationChanged`. You have to use [`orientationchange`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Gesture-event-orientationchange):

```
Titanium.Gesture.addEventListener("orientationchanged", function(evt) {
    /* ... */
});
```

Comment: it works... i simply copied your code.. so the snippet u have written has orientationchanged instead of orientationchange.